# Is there a data model, or principle, for structuring data for scripting, rather than the human eye?

Tags: google-sheets, data-science

I spend a lot of time writing scripts to automate Google Sheets using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides).

Google Apps Script can get relatively slow when the size of your data gets very big, spanning multiple sheets within multiple workbooks. I've spent my fair share of time trying to refactor my code as much as possible to reach Apps Script's 6 minute execution quota (excluding cache service).

I believe the root of the problem is the way data is being organized on sheets. An example of this is splitting 1 column into 5 columns for readability despite the data being automated. I'm sure there are other factors such as validating data once its processed into information & making sure there are no bugs but, beyond that, code doesn't care about what data looks like.

Additionally, I don't think this is a matter of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The best way, overall, to make Google Apps Script more efficient is to use less of it.

I'm not well versed in data science in general so I could definitely be wrong but, nonetheless, is this an existing principle I can learn more about? I've tried searching for this already but its hard to look for what you don't know.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect, and also can you provide your current script?

Comment: never ever use getRange(), getValue(), getValues() or setValue() or setValues() within any kind of "loop"

if you're doing that ever, you're doing it wrong and making it slow.  There are very simple ways to avoid using those methods/calls inside loops.  Any chance that's part of your trouble?

Comment: No, I have a great understanding of google apps script. To boil my question down, I'm wondering if there's a principle in data science centered around organizing data with the intent of programming with it. In other words, in my instance, data is always being structured for the human eye but structuring it like that may not be efficient for a machine's "eyes"